# ConTeXt equivalent of latexdiff

Tags: context, latexdiff

I was just wondering if anyone knows of a ConTeXt equivalent to [`latexdiff`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexdiff/)?

For those not familiar with `latexdiff`: it is a Perl script that marks up differences between 2 latex files. It is included with many LaTeX distributions.

It is used as follows:

```
$ latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex
```

Then when you compile the output `diff.tex`, it shows added text in blue, and deleted text in red strikethrough. E.g., http://haakoh.at.ifi.uio.no/latexdiff/

Does anyone knows of a ConTeXt tool that achieves something similar?

If not, can anyone offer any pointers on how the `latexdiff` Perl script might be leveraged/ported to a "`contextdiff`" equivalent?

Comment: Could you expand your question as to how exactly the tool you mention works differently from common ``diff``? Context users might not be familiar with Latex specific programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [texdiff](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/texdiff/). It should work with ConTeXt.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i was looking for. In my answer below I outline the ConTeXt pre-amble i used to get texdiff working similarly to latexdiff.

Answer (score 6):

@user21568 is right, [texdiff](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/texdiff/) works with ConTeXt.

However while the [texdiff](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/texdiff/) doco lists an example preamble for LaTeX, it doesn't offer any advice for ConTeXt.

So for the benefit of anyone else interested in using [texdiff](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/texdiff/)  with ConTeXt, here is a preamble that i have found useful:

```
% Define a blue underline bar for insertions
\definebar[insbar][color=blue, offset=-0.4, continue=yes]

% Define a red strikethrough bar for deletions
\definebar[delbar][color=red, offset=0.5, continue=yes]

% Define the insertion macro. Note the inmargin marker.
\def\TLSins#1{{\inmargin{\color[blue]{--->}}\startbar[insbar]\color[blue]{#1}\stopbar}}

% Define the deletion macro.
\def\TLSdel#1{{\inmargin{\color[red]{--->}}\startbar[delbar]\color[red]{#1}\stopbar}}

% Override ConTeXt protect command to do nothing.
% This might have undesired consequences for advanced ConTeXt users?
\def\protect{}
```

Note the redefinition of `protect`: this is a workaround of the fact that the `protect` commands that `texdiff` generates do not compile under ConTeXt - it seems  that this command has different usage in ConTeXt than in LaTeX.

Comment: ``\protect`` reinstates the common catcodes, see [its definition](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/catc-def.mkiv). Generally it is not safe to redefine but if you do make sure you don’t load any modules after that. You could try replacing the ``\protect`` calls in the generated code (but not in Context code) with ``\unexpanded`` or ``\normalprotected``).